# Display max number of td elements in table row

Tags: html, django

I am using the http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer on a page that dynamically renders multiple gauges.  The gauges are grouped by their current level.  I only want a maximum of 6 gauges in a row with any additional gauges to display on a new row.

The gauges are all working properly.  However, if there are 7 gauges with a level of "red", they are flowing off the page.

My view returns a "gauge_list" which is a list of dictionaries for each gauge like this:

```
{'cnt': 48, 'yellow_to': 66, 'level': 'yellow', 'gauge_min': 0, 'gauge_link': 'gauges:contracts', 'green_to': 33, 'gauge_max': 100, 'gauge_title': 'contracts', 'gauge_name': 'Contracts'}
```

Any suggestions on the best way to handle this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <table>
        {% for gauge in gauge_list %}
            {% if gauge.level == "red" %}
                <td><div id="{{gauge.gauge_title}}" style="width: 280px; height: 210px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <table>
        {% for gauge in gauge_list %}
            {% if gauge.level == 'yellow' %}
                <td><div id="{{gauge.gauge_title}}" style="width: 280px; height: 210px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <table>
        {% for gauge in gauge_list %}
            {% if gauge.level == 'green' %}
                <td><div id="{{gauge.gauge_title}}" style="width: 280px; height: 210px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is to either a) determine the grouped lists in the view or b) use the built-in [`groupby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag.  `groupby` requires that the list of dictionaries be arranged by the grouping key, which would be `level` here.  That's best done in the view, since you probably don't want the naive alphabetic sorting that the `dictsort` filter would give you.

```
{% regroup gauge_list by level as level_list %}
    {% for level in level_list %}
        <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <table>
              {% for gauge in level.list %}
                {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"6" %}
                  {% if not forloop.first %}</tr>{% endif %}                    
                  <tr>
                {% endif %}
                <td><div id="{{gauge.gauge_title}}" style="width: 280px; height: 210px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
              {% endfor %}
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

By doing it in the view, I mean something like providing a nested data structure instead of a simple list.  Something like:

```
levels_and_gauges = [['red', [...red guage dicts]],
                     ['yellow', [...yellow guage dicts]],
                     ['green'], [...green guage dicts]]]
```

The template code would then be something like this:

```
{% for level, guages in levels_and_guages %}
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <table>
          {% for guage in guages %}
            {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"6" %}
              {% if not forloop.first %}</tr>{% endif %}                    
              <tr>
            {% endif %}
            <td><div id="{{gauge.gauge_title}}" style="width: 280px; height: 210px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
           {% endfor %}
           </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Or you could group into 6-length rows in the view rather than the template.

Comment: I will try to see what I can do in the view.  When I slice in the template, I lose any of the gauges after 6 (unless I am doing something wrong).

Comment: Right - I thought that was what you wanted.  Sorry, did you mean to loop onto a new row after 6?

Comment: Yes sorry, guess I wasn't clear on that.  There could be more than 6 gauges on a level at any given time.  So, if there are 8 of one color, I'd like 6 on the first row, and then 2 on the next row.

Comment: I edited my original question so hopefully it is a little more clear.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I think the edited version should do that.  I'm not super thrilled about its elegance, though - if you do use something in the view to nest a data structure you might want to handle it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for level in ["red", "yellow", "green"] %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <table>
            {% for gauge in gauge_list %}
                {% if gauge.level == level %}
                    <td><div id="{{gauge.gauge_title}}" style="width: 280px; height: 210px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This definitely cleans up my code some, so I will implement this for sure. But, I am not seeing how this solves my problem.  If level is "red", and there are 8 gauges that are in red they all still display in one row.  I need a max of 6 in any row.